# Print only certain specified rows

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have data that contains several rows. Some of the rows start with values 43250, 1000.0, 500.0, 300.0 and in-between to these rows there are others rows too. However the order is as written (i.e., first the row with 43250 occurs then after few lines comes 1000.0 and so on...). And there are several occurrences of this type. What I want is:

- Print the row **CONTAINING** 43250
- Print the row just **after** the row containing 1000.0
- followed by row CONTAINING 500.0
- followed by row CONTAINING 300.0

Typical data looks like:

```
  43250 Values at 1200Z 20 Jul 1976
--------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP    THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C     K      K      K 
--------------------------------------------
 1000.0  -13                                                               
  969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  850.0                  305.0  324.9  306.2
  700.0                  309.1  315.3  309.4
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  400.0                  331.4         331.4
  300.0                  344.2         344.2

    43250 Values at 1200Z 21 Jul 1976
--------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP    THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C     K      K      K 
--------------------------------------------
 1000.0                                                                 
  500.0                  320           319
  400.0                  330           332

  43250 Values at 1200Z 22 Jul 1976
--------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP    THTA   THTE   THTV
    hPa     m      C     K      K      K 
--------------------------------------------
 1000.0                                                       
  700.0                  309.4  314.9  308.2
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  400.0                  331.0         330.2
  300.0                  340.2         345.8
  200.0                  340.3         346.4
```

and the **desired output** is:

```
  43250 Values at 1200Z 20 Jul 1976
  969.0                  306.9  356.7  309.9
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  300.0                  344.2         344.2
  43250 Values at 1200Z 22 Jul 1976                  
  700.0                  309.4  314.9  308.2
  500.0                  318.9         318.9
  300.0                  340.2         345.8
```

(See that there can also be groups of data where nothing should be printed at all. Only those occasions when they all occur together is desired. See that second chunk of data was ignored since it did not have the row containing 300.0.)

Comment: I saw your comment. In that case, sed is a poor choice and awk would be much better. I have deleted my answer. You should [edit] your question to make it more clear that there can also be groups of data where nothing should be printed at all, for example by adding a longer bit of input/output including data chunks that should be ignored.

Comment: @Benjamin W.  As per the suggestions, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following script to a file, and then call `awk -f script input.data`:

```
/43250/ { data[1] = $0 }
/500/ { data[3] = $0 }
/300/ {
    if (data[1] && data[2] && data[3]) {
        print data[1] "\n" data[2] "\n" data[3] "\n" $0;
    }
    delete data;
}
/1000/ { found = 1; next }
found { data[2] = $0; found = 0 };
```

If the line contains 43250 or 500, remember it. If the line contains 1000, save the next line. If the line contains 300, print everything if the data is complete. Start again.

Comment: Would you please explain the answer and also how to execute it. My data file is infile_1. I am not able to run it.

Comment: It seems working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This oneliner will work.

```
sed -n '/43250\|500\|300/p;/1000/{n;p}' file_name
```

Explanation:

"/43250\|500\|300/p"  Sed will search lines containing 43250, 500 or 300 and prints the output suppressing all other lines (sed -n switch ),  also looks for 1000, go to next line "/1000/n;" and prints that line.

Hope this is what you looking for. Enjoy.

Regards
Pravi

Comment: The OP wants to print the data only if it is complete.

Comment: The above oneliner doesn't yield the desired result as Michael mentioned. It must look for the complete pattern when they all occur in a bunch. Also the occurrence must be at **first column** not any random.